# I want to migrate users from one database to the next

Tags: database-connection, laravel-5.7

I am attempting to create a custom command that will migrate user data from one database to the next, This database is not normalized, very legacy, very badly made.

All of that is fine, but I am unsure, in a custom laravel command of how to connect to a different database and do select commands and get back collections of data, like you would if you were doing `User::all()`.

I wont have models for this other database, the application that uses said database is written in php 5.2.

How can I create a custom command that does select statements to another database? All the answers I find are for creating migrations to another database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define multiple database connection configurations in your `config/database.php` file, then use `DB::connection('connection_name_here')` to run queries on specific connections.

For example:

```
DB::connection('first_db')->select("...");
DB::connection('second_db')->select("...");
```

More information on multiple connections can be found in Laravel's documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database#using-multiple-database-connections